# How to convert "2014-08-10T06:34:04-0500" to SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

how to convert `2014-08-10T06:34:04-0500` to `SimpleDateFormat`, I've tried

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss-SSSS"),
```

but it is not working like that.

Edit. If somebody encounters a similar problem, than this patters - "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", will work on Android, according to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

and possibly on Java prior 1.7., and on Java 1.7 - .., use the answer that T.J. Crowder gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-0500` at the end isn't milliseconds (the `S` format character), it's an ISO-8601 timezone indicator (the [`X` format character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), in current versions of Java; note that it was added relatively recently, in Java 7). The `-` is part of the timezone indicator, not a separator, so you don't want `-` in your string.

So:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")
```

In Java 6 and earlier, you might get by with the `Z` timezone format character rather than `X`. But Java 7 came out over three years ago, so...

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X' this is  with this pattern - "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX"
And with this yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'X' - 
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-08-10T05:38:42-0500" (at offset 19). Have any suggestions?

Comment: @attels: Did you read the bit above about `X` being Java 7 and up, and how `Z` might be sufficient for Java 6 and below?

Comment: In the end yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ worked for me, thank you, T.J. Crowder

Comment: @attels: I would recommend double-checking your classpath, I think you've got some outdated JDK jar in there. Java 7's `SimpleDateFormat` **definitely** has the `X` format specifier. I don't happen to have a Java 7 install handy, but again, [the docs are clear about it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and I know I used it before Java 8 came out. FWIW, here's a sample: http://pastie.org/9459904 Could you have used `x` instead of `X`? (It does matter.)

Comment: I double checked all, compiler compliance level is 1.7 for my project,and i used capital "X", i am not sure why Z worked, but the main thing is that all worked, thank you again for the solid answer.

Comment: @attels: You're welcome, but just beware that you are clearly not using the Java 7 version of `SimpleDateFormat`. That means there **is** something wrong somewhere in your setup, if you think you're using Java 7.

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant, but this is android SimpleDateFormat class doc.: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

And there is this line:
Z time zone (RFC 822) (Time Zone) Z/ZZ/ZZZ:-0800 ZZZZ:GMT-08:00 ZZZZZ:-08:00

And there is no X mentioned there.

Comment: @attels: It is indeed relevant, that explains it. Remember that the Android SDK is **not** the JDK. It just plays one on TV. :-) (Just as Dalvik isn't a JVM, it's just really similar to one.)